# ¿Cómo habilitar CORS en una aplicación móvil PhoneGap?

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, seguridad, phonegap

Actualmente tengo una aplicación móvil hecha con phoneGap, que invoca unos servicios web mediante ajax, al probar la aplicación en un browser en mi laptop funciona bien si habilito CORS desde Chrome, el problema está en que no sé como habilitarlo desde el móvil que estoy utilizando he probado con la siguiente línea de código en xml.config y no funciona:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

¿Alguien sabe si puedo habilitar directamente en la función ajax CORS o me falta algo en la configuración de PhoneGap, o así como habilite CORS en Chrome desde mi laptop puedo hacerlo directamente en el navegador que usa Android por defecto?

Comment: ¿El webservice es tuyo? ¿No podrías habilitarlo en el servidor?

Comment: Si es mio, uso como servidor weblogic, pero no se como habilitar CORS en el servidor.

Comment: Además me dí cuenta que el problema no es en el servidor, por que la petición al servicio desde el móvil se hace y el servidor retorna los datos corretamente, lo sé porque con weblogic puedo ver a tráves de la consola las solicitudes y el flujo que toman dichas solicitudes, el problema está en que la aplicación no muestra los datos debido a un problema de seguridad CORS, incluso cuando lo probé en el browser y use la consola del browser para ver como se comporta el código se ve que la petición se genera y se obtiene la respuesta correctamente, sólo que no se imprimen los valores.

Comment: Los valores no se imprimen y como advertencia de seguridad sale un mensaje "Error falta cabacera  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ", así que active una extensión de CORS para Chrome y funcionó. Ahora sólo me falta saber como solucionarlo en PhoneGap.

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que envíes el encabezado `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ` (o limitado al sitio que quieras) dentro de la respuesta del servidor.

Comment: Ok y ¿Como hago eso?. Me podrías dar un ejemplo, la invocación la hago mediante ajax, ¿Como agrego allí el encabezado?

Comment: en phonegap no tienes que activar CORS para que funcionen las llamadas AJAX a otros dominios, salvo que estes usando el plugin de iOS de la WKWebView

Comment: Entonces como hago?? Porque la llamada a través de AJAX funciona, la petición el servidor la recibe, incluso manda la respuesta, solo que por alguna razón la respuesta se bloquea y no se muestra en la aplicación y el error es: "Error falta cabacera Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ". Que debo hacer??